# Administrative review - extra documents

Tags: united-kingdom

My tier 4 visa has been refused as I did not show documents for funds. I forgot to enclose my bank statements in the application, however I do have the sufficient funds. Can I apply for an administrative review in this case and submit the bank statements?

If no, and I have to make a new application, should a new CAS be generated? The existing CAS would not work for the new application, right?